# cordova server listen to custom HTTP methods

Tags: javascript, cordova, nanohttpd

I am using this [cordova plugin which creates a webserver](https://github.com/bykof/cordova-plugin-webserver). The way it is built I think it should be able to listen to any incominh HTTP methods but it is not working though. I am simply getting that the request is not handled.

```
webserver.onRequest(
    function(request) {
      console.log("Request method: ", request.method);
      webserver.sendResponse(
      request.requestId,
        {
          status: 200,
          body: '<html>Hello World</html>',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
         }
       }
     );
   }
)
```

Curl respones

```
>$ curl -X POST  http://192.168.1.2:1337
^C
>$ curl -X PUT  http://192.168.1.2:1337
^C
>$ curl -X DELETE  http://192.168.1.2:1337
^C
>$ curl -X NOTIFY  http://192.168.1.2:1337
BAD REQUEST: Syntax error. HTTP verb NOTIFY unhandled.
>$ curl -X SUBSCRIBE  http://192.168.1.2:1337
BAD REQUEST: Syntax error. HTTP verb SUBSCRIBE unhandled.
```

How to make it possible so that it listens to custom HTTP methods as well?